# Transferir um objeto dentro de uma metodo de uma classe para outra classe

Tags: java

Bom, sei que estou fazendo do jeito menos pratico, porém gostaria de saber como que eu faço para transferir uma instancia de uma classe para outra classe.
Estou criando um algoritmo em que eu vou chamar um metodo que esta na classe A para pegar 4 notas, e todas vão ser guardadas dentro de um vetor, porem queria chamar um outro metodo logo depois da classe B que dividisse essas 4 notas, mas não sei nem como começar. segue o codigo:

Classe MAIN em que eu vou chamar os dois metodos:

```
public class Calculadora 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    CalculadoraExec.metodoNotas();      
    }
}
```

Classe em que eu vou usar o metodo para pegar as notas:

```
    static double metodoNotas () 
    {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] notas = new double [4];
        int c2 = 1;
        for (int c=0;c<=notas.length-1; c++) 
        {
            System.out.println("NOTA "+c2);
            double n = teclado.nextDouble();
            notas[c] = n;
            c2++;
        }
        teclado.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(notas));
    return 0; 
    }
}
```

Agora como que eu faço para pegar as 4 notas digitadas e jogar para a classe Media?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ler as diversas entradas você pode seguir uma [outra thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469882/reading-multiple-scanner-inputs) sobre isso. Poderia ser tudo na mesma classe, mas como você quer necessariamente trabalhar com duas classes você pode ter a primeira para ler e a segunda para calcular.  TEndo a classe principal que controla tudo isso:

```
public class Calculadora {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] notas = A.read();
        B.divide(notas);
    }

}

class A {

    public static int[] read() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] vars = new int[4];

        System.out.println("Enter " + vars.length + " vars: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            vars[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        return vars;
    }
}

class B {
    public static void divide(int[] notas){
        // TODO
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(notas));
    }
}
```

Caso queira trabalhar com instancia como falou no tópico, basta tirar os statics e trabalhar com ´new´ criando instancias e passando como parâmetro.

```
public class Calculadora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(a);
        b.divide();
    }
}

class A {

    public int[] read() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] vars = new int[4];

        System.out.println("Enter " + vars.length + " vars: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            vars[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        return vars;
    }
}

class B {

    private A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void divide(){
        int[] notas = a.read();
        // TODO
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(notas));
    }
}
```